# Issue after Switching back from Java 17 to Java 8

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, upgrade

My Current workspace was running with Java 8 with the Gradle version -"4.7". Later I upgraded to Java 17 in the same workspace with an upgrade in gradle 7x version with other libraries. Now I am switching back to Java 8 again on the gradle version - "4.7" and hitting with below issue. I understand some class file or some lib settings has been disturbed.  Can someone please assist with this?
I have already done the "invalidate caches", removed the .gradle, .idea, and build folders.

./gradlew npmInstallDefault --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().

Could not create service of type PluginResolutionStrategyInternal using BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy().

- Exception is:

```
org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:816)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:767)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:780)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:766)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:780)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:766)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:284)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:279)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.doNewInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:179)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.newInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:108)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type PluginResolutionStrategyInternal using BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy().
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:816)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:767)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:780)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:766)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:284)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:279)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.defaultScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:301)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:293)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:814)
        ... 61 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not generate a proxy class for class org.gradle.plugin.management.internal.DefaultPluginResolutionStrategy.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:228)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.newInstance(ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.java:36)
        at org.gradle.plugin.internal.PluginUsePluginServiceRegistry$BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy(PluginUsePluginServiceRegistry.java:106)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:814)
        ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Class sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String, byte[], int, int, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.security.ProtectionDomain)'
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.define(ClassLoaderUtils.java:104)
        at org.gradle.model.internal.asm.AsmClassGenerator.define(AsmClassGenerator.java:58)
        at org.gradle.model.internal.asm.AsmClassGenerator.define(AsmClassGenerator.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AsmBackedClassGenerator$ClassBuilderImpl.generate(AsmBackedClassGenerator.java:967)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:226)
        ... 88 more
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know if you are using a version control system, but once you solve this issue, you should use different branches for different java versions

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/q/69637244/18157

Comment: Why downgrade Gradle? Why not keep the latest Gradle but target your build for Java 8?

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez - yes I will keep difference branches fo different java versions after this is solved.

Comment: @JimGarrison - In the link shared- we are adding a lib, think - switching back should not be dependent on adding any libs.

Comment: @BasilBourque - That is a separate repository all together. Hence setting up java 8 with the code compatible.

Comment: Also i observed that this particular project is still running on java 17 but i have updated all the settings.  cxo-dashboards-war % java -version
java version "17.0.8" 2023-07-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: *"Also i observed that this particular project is still running on java 17 but i have updated all the settings."* - The implication of "still running on Java 17" AND Jim Garrison's answer is that (in fact) you haven't updated all of the relevant settings ... or you haven't updated them correctly, or in all of the places that they need to be updated.

Comment: If you are running gradle from the command line ... did you update the environment variables?  See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_environment_variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This entire series of problems happened due to the gradle version download and the ".cache" folder created by gradle pertaining to that workspace. In my case - there were two problems.

1. Multiple gradle version downloads for the same workspace: For Java 8, the downloaded gradle version was 4x and for Java 17 - the downloaded gradle version was 7x in the same workspace along with the ".cache" folder which created the version compatibility issues
2. Updating the Environmental variables: When there was only one Java version, it was automatically picked up but since now we have two different versions in the same path, we would need to update the environment variables based on the Java version we want to use.

So by creating a new workspace W1 on Java 8 and another Workspace W2 on Java17 separately but updating the environment variables based on the Workspace we chose to work on, I was able to proceed.

Thanks, everyone for the input. Appreciate for sharing your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

When you read an exception message, always look for the final `Caused by:` message. This is the root cause, and the other parts of the stack trace show you why the code that throws that exception is being called.

Your root cause is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Class sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String, byte[], int, int, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.security.ProtectionDomain)'
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.define(ClassLoaderUtils.java:104)
        at org.gradle.model.internal.asm.AsmClassGenerator.define(AsmClassGenerator.java:58)
```

So the version of gradle you are using is trying to call a method which doesn't exist in the version of Java you are running with.

As the question Jim Garrison linked to points out, that method was removed in Java 11 (https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8193033).

So if you want to use grade 4.7 (I don't know why you'd use such an old version) you will need to use Java 10 or earlier.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, as stated in the question - This is for Java 8. So 4.7 should be okay. This is all the existing code and works fine in the machine where it has only Java 8 and they didn't try to upgrade to Java 17 and again move back to JAVA 8 in the same workspace. I am also checking .

Comment: "I am switching back to Java 8 again" Your issue is that you have not switched back to Java 8.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez the title says "after switching..." but certainly the context "Now I am switching back to Java 8 again" implies that the error message is after the OP believes they have made the switch. As English is often to not the first language of SO users one needs to use context and common sense in interpreting questions.